# How to rank heatmap with best score?

Tags: r

This will produce a very simpl heat map:

```
qualityScores=structure(list(Test1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Test2 = c(2L, 
 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L), Test3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), Test4 = c(3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Test5 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Test1", 
"Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
 c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"))
  samples <- rownames(qualityScores)
  tests <- colnames(qualityScores)
   testScores <- unlist(qualityScores)
   colors <- c("green", "yellow", "red")

   ggplot(melt(cbind(sample=rownames(qualityScores), qualityScores)), 
   aes(x = variable, y = sample, fill = factor(value))) + 
    geom_tile() +     scale_fill_manual(values=colors)
```

I would like to rank Y axis from the sample that has the best score (1) to the sample that has the worst score (3) based on combination of all tests?
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: `variable` and `value` is missing? You could rank them based on the sum/product/mean of proportions. Or sum of -log(proportions).

Comment: No not missing. What do you mean please?

Comment: I mean in ggplot you have `variable` and `value`, but they do not exist in your data. So yes, missing.

Comment: Variable and value are created automatically with the function melt

Comment: Aight I generally do not use `reshape` so my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just arrange them based on the sum of proportions as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
cols_to_sum <- rlang::syms(paste0('Test', 1:5)) #Put 30 here
structure(list(Test1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Test2 = c(2L, 
                                                        2L, 
                                                        2L, 1L, 3L), Test3 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), Test4 = c(3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L), Test5 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Test1", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
              c("Sample1", 
                "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5")) %>% 
    mutate(
        across(everything(), ~./sum(.)),
        rank = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(!!!cols_to_sum), ~sum(...))
    ) %>% 
    arrange(desc(rank))
        Test1 Test2     Test3     Test4     Test5      rank
Sample2   0.2   0.2 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.2222222 1.1777778
Sample1   0.2   0.2 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.1111111 1.0666667
Sample3   0.2   0.2 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.3333333 0.9555556
Sample5   0.2   0.3 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.9444444
Sample4   0.2   0.1 0.3333333 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.8555556
```

This makes each test contribute with equal weight to the final rank.

Comment: Yeah, I'll update.

Comment: Many thanks but the columns have diffent names not test1,test2;.....

Comment: Then just use `colnames(qualityScores)` instead of `paste0(...)`.